# Play Icon missing in AV Player iOS 14

Tags: swift, uikit, ios14, xcode12

I am working on a swift project, using XCode 12 and after the iOS 14 upgrade, the play icon is missing from AVPlayer. The issue is very weird

When I load the app for the first time I am able to see the play icon (ScreenShot1). After going back to the home screen and coming back, the play icon is not visible (ScreenShot2).

[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVdO9.png)

[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Df1B.png)

Currently, AVPlayer is embedded inside UIImage View. Below is the Code

```
     imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                mediaPlayer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                imageView.addSubview(mediaPlayer.view)
                mediaPlayer.view.pin(to: imageView)
                
                guard let itemURL = URL(string: asset.AssetURL) else { return }
                let item = AVPlayerItem(url: itemURL)
                let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
                mediaPlayer.player = player
                mediaPlayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                mediaPlayer.entersFullScreenWhenPlaybackBegins = true
                mediaPlayer.exitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds = true
```

Comment: i m also facing same issue @Asperi any solution please add here.Help me.Thanks..

Comment: have you any solution?